# Common practice to use scoped functions for CommonJS modules, or unnecessary?

Tags: javascript, commonjs

I'm writing my first CommonJS module.

Is it common practice to define a CommonJS module in a scoped function, like so

```
(function() {
  module.exports = ...
})();
```

or is there no value in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not necessary. Surrounding all of your code in an immediately invoked function expressions (iife) is a solution for browser-based problems.

If your module is used in Node.JS, the module will be executed in its own scope. See their [docs page](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) for examples, none of which use iife. However, if you're using a CommonJS module in a browser, you will need to bundle your CommonJS modules with a tool like watchify or commonjs-everywhere.  These tools put each module definition into its own enclosing function anyway, achieving the same protection as iife.